# can't get netbeans javafx program to run remotely on a raspberry pi 3B+ from windows 10 pc

Tags: java, raspberry-pi3, netbeans-8

I built a JavaFX program in NetBeans 8.0.2 using JDK1.8 (Java 8) but I can't get it to run remotely on a Raspberry Pi.

I've followed many tutorials on how to add the raspberry pi as a remote platform and, after some stumbling, I got it to work. The first problem I had was the password and then the directory and then I didn't realize I needed SSH enabled but I eventually got NetBeans to communicate with the raspberry pi. YAY! Until I hit the play button (Run Project button). I've had to mix and match information from multiple sources just to get the darn programs to talk correctly since everything is over 2 years old and none if it is for my combination of NetBeans and Raspberry Pi (NOTHING IS FOR THE 3 B+!).

The main thing I'm oddly getting now is:
Error: Could not find or load main class Pickage.Main

Except, the main class IS there and it runs just fine on my pc.

I've also tried rebooting the RPi but booting it to CLI (Command Line Interface) because that's apparently what you need to do (I know JFX can get pretty heavy). Still nothing.

My final attempt was to put everything I could in one shot. I made the default JavaFX program (the built in Hello World one) with no modifications to it, tested it on my pc first, then selected my remote pi settings as my runtime platform, rebooted the pi to CLI and tried to run the program again and still the same "Could not find..." error.

I've checked every tutorial I could possibly find and everything is either outdated or wrong.

There's also an error in 
\nbproject\remote-platform-impl.xml:105: The following error occurred while executing this line:
\nbproject\remote-platform-impl.xml:63: Remote command failed with exit status 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)

Which contains this line:
                    command="cd '${remote.project.dir}'; ${remote.platform.exec.prefix}'${remote.java.executable}' @{additionaljvmargs} -Dfile.encoding=${runtime.encoding} ${run.jvmargs} ${run.jvmargs.ide} -jar ${remote.dist.jar} ${application.args}"/>

I'm not sure if any of this code will help but I'm desperate at this point.

nothing happens, nothing works and nothing is progressing any further than getting netbeans and the RPI to at least connect over SSH.

I expected the default "Hello World" JavaFX project to at least work out of the box and run like so many tutorials but NOPE!. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: So, my friend and I are pretty sure that the reason it can't find the main class is because JavaFX doesn't really use the main() method. It uses the start() method. Even though the class has a main method, since it was built in the javafx launcher, it either requires JavaFX or, what you run it on, need to have some support for JavaFX through the main method (whatever that means). Neither of which, the raspberry pi has. I found advice about installing openJFX since javafx support was removed from oracle but the instructions are really confusing. Any help?

Comment: I ended up switching to swing and it's working better. Still need the desktop environment for now but maybe I can fix that later.